# TP4056 power cutoff circuit using PFET

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, charger, pulldown

I want to understand this and also to make sure this will work.

This is a TP4056 USB-C charging circuit. The circuit is almost the same as the regular one you'll find ordering from China. The only difference is - in this case, that B+ and OUT+ are separated with a PFET. I marked with a dashed red the area of schematic which is modified. PFET is there to cutoff any following load (all that is connected to OUT+) from the chargin circuit - at the moment when USB-C charger is connected.

Why I am doing this, because this is a must when it comes to safe lithium battery charging: https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056-page2.html

If I get this right, the gate of a DMP1045U will activate when supplying 5V from the charger, which will then close source to drain junction? Pull-down resistor will deactivate the gate at the moment of plugging out the USBC charger, so the source to drain current will flow again? Can pull down resistor be located as far as this from the gate?

[image]
[image]

I will now continue with the edit as "JustMe" proposed, although I am not sure I need this upgrade. Because I found this:

- Straight-forward power from USB-C. In the device, connect CC1 and CC2 to GND via resistors 5.1k. This will provide up to 3A @5V from a fairly modern USB wall charger. Max possible power in this case is 15W, obviously.

And I am not sure this circuit even need it, as the 1A is the highest charging current that can reach the battery anyway.

Excellent article: [What's the role of CC pin in Type-C solution](https://community.silabs.com/s/article/what-s-the-role-of-cc-pin-in-type-c-solution?language=en_US)

Data sheets of a [TP4056](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) and [TC4056](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1309136/FUMANELECTRONICS/TC4056A/1) are humble about this topic.
So when you order a USBC TP4056 or TC4056 from Ali-express or Amazon or elsewhere - doesn't even matter - you will not find any pulldown resistor from CC1/CC2. Actually [not even a trace from these pins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUCXD.jpg). And I found [DIY tutorial](https://www.hackster.io/diyguyChris/diy-protected-lithium-battery-charger-tp4056-14afa7), which follows exactly the same path.

However, you'll find them in the offical USBC specs document, here:
See figure 4-5 in [USB Type-C Spec R2.0](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf)

I found some [USBC 500mA circuit having these resistors](https://savageelectronics.com/usb-c-battery-charger/), and also some other elements like autofuse and blocking diode. Also some kind of inductor on GND - what exactly is that thing anyway?

However, in TP4056's data sheet it is stated: "No blocking diode is required due to the internal PMOSFET architecture".

Which means no blocking diode.

Reset-able fuse in the last schematic is [0805L075WR](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/0805L075WR/1212823) 750mA which I will add, allthough I am not sure is high enough, is it?

I decided to use bigger fuse [0ZCJ0110FF2E](https://media.distrelec.com/Web/Downloads/_t/ds/0ZCJ_eng_tds.pdf) (1.1A, 8V), because VCC on TP4056 can be 8V.

I will also replace 1.6kOhm Rprog with 1.2kOhm, which will provide 1000mA charging current, which is suitable for my 3.7V 14500 battery. 1000mA is MAX. On [page 3 of TP4056 Data Sheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf), you will find the exact Rprog current setting.

I did add another 1uF bypass capacitor (C9) on the battery, which I am not yet sure if it will stay there.

Here is the new edit:
[image]

Comment: That's not an USB-C compatible circuit. Someone just has replaced MicroUSB connector with Type-C connector and expects it to work, but in real life, USB-C supplies would not even detect that anything is plugged in, and will not give 5V out.

Comment: the question "I replaced an old USB connector with Type-C and now it does not work" has been asked here many times in different forms, with correct answers, so you can search here. The problem is there are so many people that do stuff without knowing about the subject and write blogs or do videos about what they "hacked" and then other people follow them. If you want to understand something, read about it from some official source. For example, the whole USB standard can be freely downloaded and read by everyone, so you have a good question, why people still get it wrong.

Comment: The IC just takes 5V in from any supply. It's just the USB interface you drew is wrong. Online shops do sell also modules with properly designed Type-C inlets.

Comment: @Justme FIXED! Are you able to answer the main question?

Comment: Also U2's GND is floating.

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç wow, I missed that one. Thank you! I corrected it now - check png. This should be it, right?

Comment: @Domenico I don't know what you fixed. No USB-C supply would detect anything being connected and would not give power to your circuit. Like I said, it is not enough to replace the connector. You need to use the CC pins as per USB specs so a power supply will detect it's connected to something that wants to pull power.

Comment: `This should be it, right?` nope, still floating. Check DW01's GND and  the 100n cap next to it. It goes nowhere. Also, your edit now shorts the battery with 100R resistor.

Comment: @Justme I see. I think I found something: https://savageelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/06d375bfef8f4fa0b42da1681effa5a6-1024x538.png 

So is it like this? CC1 & CC2 > 5k1 > GND, GND 1 & 2 > L1 > GND, VBUS 1 & 2 > F1 > D1 > VCC, and shield is going to GND. Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç I really messed this time. Can you check it once more? Thanks for saving my ass.

Comment: Now it looks good. But I couldn't understand the DMP1045's role here. It'll be on when there's no supply from USB, and off when there's at least 3V coming from USB. Is that how you want it to be?

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç yes, this is exactly the role of DMP, it will separate a charger from the load while charging. If this would not be done, a load will affect the battery reference, so over-voltage level can be disrubted. This is only in case someone forget to switch it off manually. Do you think this PFET is good enough for the particular job?

Comment: @Justme : **"I don't know what you fixed. No USB-C supply would detect anything being connected and would not give power to your circuit."**  ** I beg to differ. Read what I wrote under the last edit.

Comment: @Domenico You can choose to not believe what USB specs say and clone the garbage that the online shops sell, or even try to make a device that works with USB-C supplies. The USB specs are clear on this, an USB-C power supply must not provide any voltage on output unless it detects the resistors on your device - so no resistors, no voltage out either. Those garbage products will only work with Type-A to Type-C cable because they have to always pass power from Type-A to Type-C. Without resistors they do not get any power from Type-C supply.

Comment: @Justme Ok then. I will listen to you. As you can see I invested quite some time in the research. All I am asking you is to help me finish this, so my kids will finally be able to have my company again. FUSE? Yes or no? PFET OK? inductor on GND, what kind of?